# Handling variables in jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I am generating CSV file, I want to use one of the variable(format - 123456789) from CSV  and want to change it social security number format.
How can i do that in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

You can format value using JSR 223 Sampler/Post Processor with language javascript/nashorn using script with given socialSecurityNumber create formatted value in socialSecurityNumberFormat:

```
socialSecurityNumber = "123456789";// or get from variable name as : vars.get("socialSecurityNumber")
vars.put("socialSecurityNumberFormat", socialSecurityNumber.substring(0,3) + "-" + socialSecurityNumber.substring(3, 6) + "-" + socialSecurityNumber.substring(6));
```